# Impedir git merge quando existir conflito

Tags: git

Quando estou usando o GitHub for Desktop, e faço um pull ou push, o App apenas informa que um arquivo está em conflito e nada acontece. mas quando uso o gitbash, inicia um merge automaticamente.

Eu gostaria que sempre que efetuasse um `git pull` ou `git push` no gitbash, o sistema apenas desse um erro informando o arquivo que está em conflito e parasse o processo, semelhando ao GitHub for Desktop.

Eu prefiro que sempre que um arquivo esteja em conflito, o processo seja, copiar as alterações do desenvolvedor para o bloco de nota, limpar todas as alterações (`git checkout -- .`, ...), efetuar um novo git pull, repassar as alterações do desenvolvedor para o novo arquivo, e tentar um `git add / git commit / git push`.

De maneira inescapável, sempre que um desenvolvedor efetua um git push no gitbash, surge um merge automaticamente, ele sempre acaba comitando, e sempre quebra o projeto.

Minha duvida é: tem algum comando para o git pull e git push que impeça o merge, e caso haja um conflito, não baixa e nem envia as alterações para o origin?
Exemplo: `git pull --strategy="abort case conflict"`?

Comment: Experimente `git pull --ff-only`.

Comment: Quem sabe possa te ajudar: [How to prevent an automerge using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235010/how-to-prevent-an-automerge-using-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode instruir os desenvolvedores que, ao detectarem o problema, abortem o `merge` do `git pull` com conflitos, usando:

```
git merge --abort
```

No pior caso, você pode criar algum script ou alias de comando que faça isto por você quando o conflito for detectado, instruindo que todos os desenvolvedores utilizem ele. Pensando em um quase pseudocódigo para este script, ficaria:

```
git pull | grep 'Unmerged paths' &> /dev/null
if [ $? == 0 ]; then
   git merge --abort
fi
```

E o nome do script/comando poderia ser algo como `git-pull`.

Muito do que você falou refere-se aos desenvolvedores não entenderem como funciona o processo de resolução de conflitos do Git. Sem que todos aprendam de forma apropriada como o Git funciona, fica complicado pensar em uma solução boa.